# find frequency of substring in a set of strings

Tags: r, perl

I have as input a gene list where each genes has a header like >SomeText.
For each gene I would like to find the frequency of the string `GTG`. (number of occurences divided by length of gene). The string should only be counted if it starts at position 1,4,7,10 etc (every thids position).

```
 >ENST00000619537.4 cds:known chromosome:GRCh38:21:6560714:6564489:1 gene:ENSG00000276076.4 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:CH507-152C13.3 description:alpha-crystallin A chain  [Source:RefSeq peptide;Acc:NP_001300979]
ATGGATGTGACCATCCAGCACCCCTGGTTCAAGCGCACCCTGGGGCCCTTCTACCCCAGC
CGGCTGTTCGACCAGTTTTTCGGCGAGGGCCTTTTTGAGTATGACCTGCTGCCCTTCCTG
TCGTCCACCATCAGCCCCTACTACCGCCAGTCCCTCTTCCGCACCGTGCTGGACTCCGGC
ATCTCTGAGGTTCGATCCGACCGGGACAAGTTCGTCATCTTCCTCGATGTGAAGCACTTC
TCCCCGGAGGACCTCACCGTGAAGGTGCAGGACGACTTTGTGGAGATCCACGGAAAGCAC
AACGAGCGCCAGGACGACCACGGCTACATTTCCCGTGAGTTCCACCGCCGCTACCGCCTG
CCGTCCAACGTGGACCAGTCGGCCCTCTCTTGCTCCCTGTCTGCCGATGGCATGCTGACC
TTCTGTGGCCCCAAGATCCAGACTGGCCTGGATGCCACCCACGCCGAGCGAGCCATCCCC
GTGTCGCGGGAGGAGAAGCCCACCTCGGCTCCCTCGTCCTAA
>ENST00000624019.3 cds:known chromosome:GRCh38:21:6561284:6563978:1 gene:ENSG00000276076.4 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:CH507-152C13.3 description:alpha-crystallin A chain  [Source:RefSeq peptide;Acc:NP_001300979]
ATGGACGCCCCCCCCCCCCACCCAACCACAGGCCTCCTCTCTGAGCCACGGGTTCGATCC
GACCGGGACAAGTTCGTCATCTTCCTCGATGTGAAGCACTTCTCCCCGGAGGACCTCACC
GTGAAGGTGCAGGACGACTTTGTGGAGATCCACGGAAAGCACAACGAGCGCCAGGACGAC
CACGGCTACATTTCCCGTGAGTTCCACCGCCGCTACCGCCTGCCGTCCAACGTGGACCAG
TCGGCCCTCTCTTGCTCCCTGTCTGCCGATGGCATGCTGACCTTCTGTGGCCCCAAGATC
CAGACTGGCCTGGATGCCACCCACGCCGAGCGAGCCATCCCCGTGTCGCGGGAGGAGAAG
CCCACCTCGGCTCCCTCGTCCTAA
>ENST00000624932.1 cds:known chromosome:GRCh38:21:6561954:6564203:1 gene:ENSG00000276076.4 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:CH507-152C13.3 description:alpha-crystallin A chain  [Source:RefSeq peptide;Acc:NP_001300979]
ATGCCTGTCTGTCCAGGAGACAGTCACAGGCCCCCGAAAGCTCTGCCCCACTTGGTGTGT
GGGAGAAGAGGCCGGCAGGTTCGATCCGACCGGGACAAGTTCGTCATCTTCCTCGATGTG
AAGCACTTCTCCCCGGAGGACCTCACCGTGAAGGTGCAGGACGACTTTGTGGAGATCCAC
GGAAAGCACAACGAGCGCCAGGACGACCACGGCTACATTTCCCGTGAGTTCCACCGCCGC
TACCGCCTGCCGTCCAACGTGGACCAGTCGGCCCTCTCTTGCTCCCTGTCTGCCGATGGC
ATGCTGACCTTCTGTGGCCCCAAGATCCAGACTGGCCTGGATGCCACCCACGCCGAGCGA
GCCATCCCCGTGTCGCGGGAGGAGAAGCCCACCTCGGCTCCCTCGTCCTAA
```

Output:

```
Gene   Frequency
Gene1: 3
Gene2 6.3
....
```

I was thinging of something like this, but I dont now how to define the positions requirements:

```
freq <- sapply(gregexpr("GTG",x),function(x)if(x[[1]]!=-1) length(x) else 0)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at solving this already?

Comment: Did you tag with perl because you are using Perl regexes in R, or because you would be fine with a pure Perl solution as well?

Comment: I would like to use perl because my input is very large, maybe to large to be loaded in R

Comment: Can you expand on 'divided by length' - if there's one instance of `GTG` in the first string, does that mean the 'frequency' should be `1/207`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution that does not use a pattern match. Not that it will matter much.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $gene;
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^>(.+)/ ) {
        $gene = $1;
        next;
    }

    chomp $line;

    printf "%s: %s\n", 
        $gene, 
        ( grep { $_ eq 'GTG' } split /(...)/, $line ) / length $line;
}
```

Output:

```
Gene1: 0.00483091787439614
Gene2: 0
Gene3: 0.00302114803625378
```

It is essentially similar to Sobrique's answer, but assumes that the gene lines contain the right characters. It splits up the gene string into a list of three-character pieces and takes the ones that are literally `GTG`.

The splitting works by abusing the fact that `split` uses a pattern as the delimiter, and that it will also capture the delimiter if a capture group is used. Here's an example.

```
my @foo = split /(...)/, '1234567890';
p @foo; # from Data::Printer

__END__
[
    [0] "",
    [1] 123,
    [2] "",
    [3] 456,
    [4] "",
    [5] 789,
    [6] 0
]
```

The empty elements get filter out by `grep`. It might not be the most efficient way, but it gets the job done.

---

You can run it by calling `perl foo.pl horribly-large-gene-sequence.file`.

Comment: `split/(...)/` to split on 3 characters?

Comment: `$line =~ /(...)/g` or `unpack('(a3)*', $line)` would make more sense than `split /(...)/, $line`

Comment: My input looks a bit different, could you check how linebreaks affect the output?

Comment: @user2300940 this approach is not working if there are line breaks in between. You edited the question after accepting a solution. That's not how Stack Overflow is supposed to work. You now pose a completely different problem. I suggest you ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea in R using `stringi`.

We use `stri_locate_all_fixed()` to find the `start` and `end` position of each `GTG` occurence. Then we create a column `condition` to test if `start` position is in `1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 ...`.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(stri_locate_all_fixed(gene1, "GTG")) %>%
  mutate(condition = start %in% seq(1, nchar(gene), 3))
```

Which gives:

```
#  start end condition
#1     4   6      TRUE
```

---

If you want to generalize this to a list of genes, you could do:

```
lst <- list(gene1, gene2, gene3)

res <- lapply(lst, function(x) { 
  data.frame(stri_locate_all_fixed(x, "GTG")) %>% 
    mutate(condition = start %in% seq(1, nchar(x), 3))
})
```

Which would give:

```
#[[1]]
#  start end condition
#1     4   6      TRUE
#
#[[2]]
#  start end condition
#1    NA  NA     FALSE
#
#[[3]]
#  start end condition
#1     3   5     FALSE
#2     9  11     FALSE
#3    21  23     FALSE
#4    70  72      TRUE
#5    75  77     FALSE
```

Following @Sobrique's comment, if *divided by length* means *number of occurences respecting condition divided by total number of char in each gene*,  you could do:

```
lapply(1:length(res), function(x) sum(res[[x]][["condition"]]) / nchar(lst[[x]]))
```

Which would give:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.004830918
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.003021148
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl solution that does as you ask

But I don't understand how your example output is derived: the first and last sequences have only one occurrence of `GTG` in the positions you require, and the second sequence has none at all. That means the outputs are `1 / 207`, `0 / 74`, and `1 / 331` respectively. None of those are anything like `3` and `6.3` that you say you're expecting

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

print "Gene   Frequency\n";

my $name;

local $/ = '>';

while ( <> ) {

    chomp;

    next unless /\S/;

    my ($name, $seq) = split /\n/, $_, 2;
    $seq =~ tr/A-Z//cd;

    my $n = 0;
    while ( $seq =~ /(?=GTG)/g ) {
        ++$n if $-[0] % 3 == 0;
    }

    printf "%-7s%.6f\n", $name, $n / length($seq);
}
```

#### output

```
Gene   Frequency
Gene1  0.004831
Gene2  0.000000
Gene3  0.003021
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here. Perfectly viable solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have an R solution. I've hacked something together in `perl` because you tagged it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $target = 'GTG'; 

local $/ = "\n>"; 
while ( <> ) {
    my ($gene) = m/(Gene\d+)/;  
    my @hits = grep { /^$target$/ } m/ ( [GTCA]{3} ) /xg;
    print "$gene: ".( scalar @hits), "\n";
}
```

This doesn't give the same results as your input though:

```
Gene1: 1
Gene2: 0
Gene3: 1
```

I'm decomposing your string into 3 element lists, and looking for ones that specifically match. (And I haven't divided by length, as I'm not entirely clear if that's the actual string length in letters, or some other metric).

Including length matching - we need to capture both name and string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = "\n>";
while (<>) {
   my ($gene, $gene_str) = m/(Gene\d+)\n([GTCA]+)/m;
   my @hits = grep { /^GTG$/ } $gene_str =~ m/ ( [GTCA]{3} ) /xg;   

   print "$gene: " .  @hits . "/". length ( $gene_str ), " = ", @hits / length($gene_str), "\n";

}
```

We use `<>` which is the 'magic' filehandle, and tells perl to read from *either* `STDIN` or a file specified on command line. Much like `sed` or `grep` does.

With your input:

```
Gene1: 1/207 = 0.00483091787439614
Gene2: 0/74 = 0
Gene3: 1/331 = 0.00302114803625378
```

Comment: My ouput was just an example

Comment: Thanks, looks nice. String lengths is number of letters. How would you include that?  How do you call the input data?

Comment: Edited. `<>` is a really handy feature of perl, worth learning about.

Comment: By the way. Is it possible to get the frequency output as a separate column. I would like to sort the output based on frequency. Usually I would to sort -nk2, but the frequency is not the second column it seems

Comment: trivially. Edit that print line; job done. The frequency would be column 4 in the example above. But `print "$gene ", @hits / length($gene_str), "\n";` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I created based on your requirement. I am pretty sure there are alternate ways better than this but this solves the problem.

```
require(stringi)

input_gene_list<- list(gene1= "GTGGGGGTTTGTGGGGGTG", gene2= "GTGGGGGTTTGTGGGGGTG", gene3= "GTGGGGGTTTGTGGGGGTG")

gene_counter<- function(gene){
      x<- gene
      y<- gsub(pattern = "GTG",replacement =  "GTG ", x = x, perl=TRUE)

      if(str_count(y,pattern = "GTG")) {

        gene_count<- unlist(gregexpr(pattern = " ", y))

          counter<- 0
          for(i in 1:length(gene_count)){
            if((gene_count[i] %% 3) == 1) counter=counter+1
          }
          return(counter/nchar(x))
        }
}


output_list<- lapply(input_gene_list, function(x) gene_counter(x))

result<- t(as.data.frame(output_list))
```

> result

```
           [,1]
gene1 0.1052632
gene2 0.1052632
gene3 0.1052632
```

Also share your thoughts on it! Thanks!

Comment: I argue, whoever has downvoted this answer, can you please quote a reason or atleast try the solution yourself. I don't see a reason to downvote it without an explanation.

Comment: I have received a downvote myself, and it has been commented on by a third party. I suggest that you learn to live with it: it's only -1 point

Comment: I am not concerned about negative points at all. I was just thinking that there should be a good reason for downvoting. It will at least let the person know what is wrong with his approach. I just want to learn along the way with other great people here.

Comment: Votes are cast anonymously, and it is futile to demand an explanation. I trust that your country has anonymous voting for a democratic government? Do you see them dancing and accusing over every vote for the opposition? It is odd for someone who poses as Aladdin to demand openness and honesty from their critics